# Appengine Go devserver build issue

Tags: google-app-engine, go

i have updated the go version from 1.4.1 to 1.4.2, and also now using appengine latest go sdk 1.9.18, when i try to run the existing project i get the following error ,

**google_appengine/goroot/pkg/darwin_amd64/appengine.a: object is [darwin amd64 go1.4.2 X:precisestack] expected [darwin amd64 go1.4.1 (appengine-1.9.18) X:precisestack]**

i know its an problem with file build with existing version and trying to run with new version, may i know how can i fix this issue ?

Thanks!

Comment: appengine-1.9.19 uses go1.4.2 binaries so upgrading the package should be enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest go version is 1.4.2, but the AppEngine Go SDK uses a bundled Go runtime with version 1.4.1!

That means you can't use an "external" 1.4.2 Go library to compile your sources. If you develop an app for AppEngine in Go, you can't (shouldn't) even use any Go library except the one that is bundled in the Go AppEngine SDK!

And in fact, you don't have to. The SDK contains a `goapp` command similar to the `go` tool with which you can run and test your app locally and you can deploy it to production environment. To run/test your app locally, use the `goapp serve` command, to deploy it to production environment, use the `goapp depploy` command.

So what you should do is delete any package objects compiled with Go 1.4.2, and use only the `goapp` (part of the SDK) command to run/test/deploy your application.

Note that you don't even have to install any package objects as the `goapp deploy` command uploads your app in *source* form and it is compiled into executable native binary on the appengine servers.

Comment: Thank you for answering, i indeed use goapp command for running  and deploying my application, but i use GoSublime for development , which i have configured to go build on file save, so now when i set the GOROOT to appengine sdk path, i get this error  
"go build runtime: darwin/amd64 must be bootstrapped using make.bash", any idea on this? i can compile go file now

Comment: i have got that issue fixed, so now source code is compiled with appengine go runtime , but still am getting the same issue

Comment: @Ramesh It is because you already have package objects compiled with Go 1.4.2. Remove all your package objects. If you can't tell which one is with 1.4.2, try deleting all, or download a new, fresh copy of the Go AppEngine SDK.